# Each element of a real orthogonal matrix is equal to its cofactor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

If $A =(a_{ij})$ be a real orthogonal matrix with $\det A = 1$, prove that each element $a_{rs}$ of $A$ is equal to its cofactor $A_{rs}$ in $\det A$.
I got this basic problem from my text book and somehow I couldn't proceed, please help me to get this result.

Answer (score 2):

$A^t = A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A}(\operatorname{cofactor}(A))^t\quad$
 implies $\quad A = \operatorname{cofactor}(A)\quad$ only if $\quad\det A=1$

The condition $\det A = 1$ is needed, since the determinant appears on the inverse matrix formula. For a general real orthogonal matrix you would get

$A = \frac{1}{\det A}\operatorname{cofactor}(A)$

so each element would be proportional to its cofactor, with $\frac{1}{\det A}$ being the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

$A^t = A^{-1} = (\operatorname{cofactor}(A))^t $ implies $A = \operatorname{cofactor}(A)$ and I am not sure why $A$ should have determinant $1$. It seems the conclusion is true for any real orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks.Even I also think the same for det A=I bcuase it is obvious.